# How to multiply values in each row in gridview

Tags: c#

How would i multiply individual cells in a row and output it to another cell, in this case multiplying the price and discount than multiply the amount, then output the result into the orice cell.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/huMx2.png

The code i have right now multiplies everything in the gridview by the last discount entered and doesn't multiply each row individualy

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Column in POSDGV.Rows)
                        {
                            Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = ((Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) - ((Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Discount"].Index].Value)))) *Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value));

                        }
```

full code

```
 Button BtnGlobal = (Button)sender;
            var global = BtnGlobal.Text;
         
            foreach (Book book in MyBooks)
            {
                if (global == book.BookName)
                {
                    Arraytxt.Text = Arraytxt.Text + book.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            if (global.ToLower().Contains('%'))
            {
                //Discount
                Button Discount = (Button)sender;
                
                //Discount Spliter
                string DiscountInput = Discount.Text;
                var DiscountSplit = Regex.Match(DiscountInput, @"\d{2,3}");
                int length = DiscountSplit.ToString().Substring(DiscountSplit.ToString().IndexOf(".") + 1).Length;
                if (length == 2)
                {
                    int row = 0;
                    row = POSDGV.Rows.Count - 1;
                    POSDGV["Discount", row].Value = "0." + DiscountSplit.ToString();
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow Column in POSDGV.Rows)
                        {
                            Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = ((Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) - ((Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Discount"].Index].Value)))) *Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value));

                        }
                    } 
                    
                }
                else if (length == 3)
                {
                    int row = 0;
                    row = POSDGV.Rows.Count - 1;
                    POSDGV["Discount", row].Value = 0;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow Column in POSDGV.Rows)
                    {
                        Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = (((Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) - ((Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Discount"].Index].Value)))) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value))) * 0;
                    }
                }
                decimal sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                }
                lblSub.Text = sum.ToString("c2");
                var GST = sum * 0.10m;
                lblGST.Text = GST.ToString("c2");
                lblTotal.Text = (sum + GST).ToString("c2");

                Booktxt.Clear();
                Pricetxt.Clear();
                Arraytxt.Clear();

            }
            else
            {
                //Item Buttons
                foreach (Book book in MyBooks)
                {
                    if (global == book.BookName)
                    {
                        Arraytxt.Text = Arraytxt.Text + book.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                }
                //Item Spliter
                string input = Arraytxt.Text;
                var PriceSplit = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=\$)\d+");
                var BookSplit = Regex.Match(input, @"[^\$]*");

                Booktxt.Text = BookSplit.ToString();
                Pricetxt.Text = PriceSplit.ToString();
                
                //Item Adder
                int row = 0;
                POSDGV.Rows.Add();
                row = POSDGV.Rows.Count - 1;
                POSDGV["BookName", row].Value = Booktxt.Text;
                POSDGV["Price", row].Value = Pricetxt.Text;
                POSDGV["Amount", row].Value = 1;

                //Calculation
                foreach (DataGridViewRow Column in POSDGV.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null)
                        {
                            Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["FinalPrice"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Price"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Discount"].Index].Value)) * Convert.ToDouble(Column.Cells[POSDGV.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                int buffer = 0;
                buffer = POSDGV.Rows.Count - 1;
                POSDGV["Discount", buffer].Value = 1;

                //GST, Subtotal and total
                decimal sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                }
                lblSub.Text = sum.ToString("c2");
                var GST = sum * 0.10m;
                lblGST.Text = GST.ToString("c2");
                lblTotal.Text = (sum + GST).ToString("c2");

                Booktxt.Clear();
                Pricetxt.Clear();
                Arraytxt.Clear();
```

Input 1
https://imgur.com/aTp0jNX

Input 2
https://imgur.com/rZSkE0j

Input 3
https://imgur.com/yeGOOao

Answer (score 0):

Do operation on List which you are assigning to the DataGrid.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product() { Amount = 10, Disc = 2 });
        products.Add(new Product() { Amount = 11, Disc = 3 });
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = products;
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            item.Price = item.Amount * item.Disc;
        }
    }

}
public class Product
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Disc { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but there wont be a discount every time and in those cases i just need to multiply price and amount

Comment: @ThatOneGuy I don't think I understood your question completely. Do you mean this doesn't happen for every record? Do you have any dependency for whom this is supposed to happen?

Comment: i have edited the post to show the full code, so if there is a discount i want it to multiplt each row and include the dsicount in the math but if there isnt then for each row multiply price by amount

Comment: @ThatOneGuy I would want help but I dont understand what is your problem. You have some error when you try update columns? or you dont know how to such a "if"?

Comment: This is the best way i can explain it, ive added pictures but in the images you can see that in the 2nd and 3rd pictures there are discount's present but they aren't being applied to the final price, my problem is i dont know why this is happening. The original price of the item is $15

Comment: @ThatOneGuy it seem you take 1 discount for all row. I cant debug this program. This line looking wrong. Why you take Discount from button. Button Discount = (Button)sender; string DiscountInput = Discount.Text;